# Linq query not retrieving up to date data after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, linq

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to Linq. I am able to successfully alter data using post. For example I can make Example->test = 0 from Example->test = 1. I am unable however to retrieve that updated data unless I restart my server. So unless I restart the server it will keep showing my original query result of Example->test = 1.

My simplified Query

```
public IEnumerable<Example> GetCustomerBillingInformation(string customerID)
    {
        var query = _dataContext.Example.AddQueryOption("$filter", "CustomerID eq " + customerID).AddQueryOption("$skip", 0).AddQueryOption("$top", 1);

        var result = query.BeginExecute(null, query);

        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        return query.EndExecute(result);
    }
```

I've been doing a bunch of digging trying to make sense of the problem but have not yet been successful. My thoughts are that I need to refresh my context somehow?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Can you share the code which `make Example->test == 0 from Example->test == 1.` ?

Comment: Where did you get that query? (What tutorial tells you to query the db like this? What db are you using?) Seems there is no LINQ here.